# OpenX 2.8.10 Video Ad

Tags: ads, myisam, openx

I'm trying to create a new video ad with OpenX 2.8.10 AdServe, but am getting the following error:

```
PEAR Error

MDB2 Error: syntax error
_doQuery: [Error message: Could not execute statement]
[Last executed query: CREATE TABLE banner_vast_element_seq (id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, PRIMARY KEY (id)) TYPE=MYISAM]
[Native code: 1064]
[Native message: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'TYPE=MYISAM' at line 1]



PEAR Error

MDB2 Error: syntax error
[Error message: on demand sequence banner_vast_element could not be created]



PEAR Error

DB_DataObject Error: [mdb2_error: message="MDB2 Error: syntax error" code=-2 mode=callback callback=pearErrorHandler prefix="" info="[Error message: on demand sequence banner_vast_element could not be created] "]
```

Any solution? How can I know in what PHP class the error occurs (it works when I change `TYPE=MyISAM` to `ENGINE=MyISAM`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The file is `/lib/pear/MDB2/Driver/Manager/mysql.php`. On line 842, change `TYPE=` to `ENGINE=`.

PS: It's not a `PHP` issue.

Comment: How to you know that the erros was in this file?It´s to know for future errors.You save my week!